# How to keep changing background color in wordpress tweny sixteen theme on every refresh?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background, themes

I am using WordPress twenty sixteen theme and want to change color of background on every refresh of page.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you mean that black background ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Wordpress but I think you are capable of overriding the background color on yourself.
What you could do:
 - Make an array in JavaScript which contains a few background-color codes (hexadecimal) that you like, or generate a hexadecimal.
 - Then generate a random number via. JavaScript (Math.random()) that's within the boundaries of the color array you've made.
 - Use JavaScript / jQuery to overwrite the background-color. ($("where-to-overwrite").css("background-color", >result of your randomness<);

If it's important to not get the color twice, you could save the last color in a cookie and compare it with the next occurring color.

Comment: i like your answer but i am new to javascript so can you link some tutorial related to these?

Comment: someone already wrote you some code, if it doesn't work I can write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use javascript for this to work

```
function ran_col() { //function name
            var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
            var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
            document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
        }
```

You can check out the question at [Team Tree House](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/random-background-color)